# Center a dynamic width div inside a fixed width div

Tags: html, css, position, positioning

I have quite a bit of experience with css and even this problem has stumped me.

I am theme-ing the NextGen gallery plugin for Wordpress, which means I don't really have control over the HTML, and I have a problem trying to line up the images.

In NextGen the maximum size of images is 200px x 200px. The images are thumbnails of larger images, each with its own constraints in size and dimension but all under 200px x 200px

**The main aim:**
The class image is fixed width but its width changes depending on the image that is within it. The class imageBox surrounds images and has its width fixed to the maximum width of images (200px wide, 200px high). For the images that are not 200px wide I want them to line up in the center of the imageBox.

**The basic HTML generated by NextGen Gallery:**

```
<div class="imageBox">
   <div class="image">
      <img />
   </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS so far:**

```
.imageBox{
    width: 218px;
    height: 218px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.image{
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I have used absolute positioning to ensure the images are all lined up along their bottom edge, thus the bottom:0px.

Any help would be great.

**EDIT**
Messed up the css, had the classes the wrong way round.

Comment: Incase this makes it easier: I know how to do each of the parts easily: Center a div - margin left and right auto; Align bottoms of divs to parent div - position relative on parent, position absolute on child, bottom 0px on child; Problem is that these two things are mutually exclusive, you can't have one, while having the other.

Comment: I have added the actual solution as an answer, in case anyone is looking for a similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to give a fixed 200px width to the image class and set it with position absolute and bottom 0px. This causes it to snap to the bottom of the imageBox class while taking the full width of its container.

Since the image div is now at the bottom and the full width, all thats needed is to center the image so I applied margin 0px auto to the image > img class, centering the image and solving my problem.

This can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JZzWa/).

Comment: So you wanted your images centered at the bottom of the container?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.image{
    width: 218px;
    height: 218px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: I had the css classes the wrong way round, sorry. The imageBox class is fixed, the image inside it has a smaller size (at most 200px x 200px) and is absolute to the bottom of the imageBox div. Since it's position is absolute things like text-align won't have an effect (that and since divs are block level elements on compliant browsers text-align shouldn't work)

Comment: text-align: center was not the point of my answer. But this line: margin: 0 px   Ok, I am glad you solved it your way.

Comment: No, I haven't solved it. Just that your solution wouldn't work. Messed up in my comment above, I meant that margin 0px auto wouldn't work either. Since the image is position absolute and bottom 0px the margin has no effect on the positioning

Answer (score 1):

This simplified sample, which is working if you have the specified image, works out pretty well:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Centered images</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .imageBox
        {
            float: left;
            background: cyan;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 200px;
        }
        img
        {
            vertical-align: middle;
            background: magenta;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 2px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="imageBox">
        <img src="img.png" width="200px" alt="Image." />
    </div>
    <div class="imageBox">
        <img src="img.png" width="190px" alt="Image." />
    </div>
    <div class="imageBox">
        <img src="img.png" width="180px" alt="Image." />
    </div>
</body></html>
```

There is a minor vertical `2px` difference in Internet Explorer 7 and Opera.

The trick here is to use the `vertical-align` property. It is a bit special and it is used in combination with the `line-height` property on the parent element.

**More information:**

- [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with wordpress, so I'm not sure what the restrictions are; but can you override their css with an important tag?

```
.image{
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: The only css being applied to these elements are the css shown in my question, so !important wouldn't be overriding anything, since there is nothing to override